# Convert A Date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a value set in my database as `04/01/2019`.

I need to construct a script in either PHP or MySQL that goes through each line in the table that has this value, and convert the string to `2019-04-01`.

Dates will vary, so `02/01/2019` has to be converted to `2019-02-01`, etc.

I have been reading for hours. No one has given an answer that I can modify that will do what I need.

Can someone tell me how I can go about this? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting"? In what format is stored your value? Etc.

Comment: The field is a longtext. I'm updating a meta value, the column name is meta_value. I just want to read the date (02/01/2019), change it to 2019-02-01, and then save it back to that column in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
UPDATE table SET field =  str_to_date(  field, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Comment: Well, I am trying this:

UPDATE `meta_value` SET `meta_value`= STR_TO_DATE(`meta_value`,'%Y-%m-%d') WHERE `meta_key` = '16' AND (WHERE `entry_id` = '1980');

And it tells me syntax is off.

Comment: also str_to_date expects to get the format the string is in as a second parameter '%m/%d/%Y' in your case, not the format you want to convert to. It will be in YYYY-MM-DD anyhow. Checkout the w3schools link.

Comment: Yeah I am looking at it now.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `str_to_date()`:

```
select str_to_date('04/01/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
select str_to_date('04/01/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

given your locale.

Answer (score 0):

The method str_to_date() will fix your issue, below is an example of your desired output

```
select str_to_date('04/01/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
```